# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method question

Tags: objective-c

First of all I beg your pardon but I am a newbie and trying to learn Objective-C. I was studying the UITableView when I found this method:

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

I read the [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for UITableView and some examples but I don't understand one thing: what calls this method and what validates its parameters (eg. indexPath)?

Comment: I don't understand the sense of -1, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is called by the UITableView when the table needs another cell to display. The table view calls the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method on the object pointed to with the table view's `dataSource` property.

So if you've got a view controller, you implement the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` there, call `[myTableView setDataSource:self]` and the table view will call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` once it needs to display a new cell for the given index path (row).

Of course, you also need to implement the other required method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` of the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol and maybe a few other of its methods. Otherwise the table view would even know how many sections and rows it should display.

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear, thanks. I could not find useful documentation aside from your post (and I own many books...)